# Powering 12V keypad through Arduino Uno

Tags: arduino-uno

Arduino Uno

I'm currently working on a project which will involve entering a sequence on a 12V keypad. The keypad and its documentation can be found here: https://www.jaycar.com.au/digital-keypad-with-rfid-access-control/p/LA5353

[image: key pad]

They keypad wants 9-18V AC/12~24V DC. I'll be using the keypad to output 26 bit Wiegand to the Arduino. I'm just wondering the best way to power this system. The schematics included with the keypad show that the keypad and the controller  (Arduino) should be sharing a power source. See image attached.

How can I power the 12-24V keypad through the arduino without frying it?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

> How can I power the 12-24V keypad through the arduino without frying it?

If you power the Arduino with slightly more than 12V (through the barrel jack) then you can get 12V (or slightly less than you power the Arduino with) from the VIN pin.

However the Arduino's on-board voltage regulator does tend to get a little hot when such a high voltage is used to power it. Better is just to power the keypad separately from the correct power source.

*And don't forget to connect the grounds together.*

Comment: Thanks for the information Majenko. So there's no issue with using a seperate power supply for the keypad and then grounding it with the Arduinos ground pin? Also, can i plug the d0 and d1 lines directly into the Arduino, or do i need to manage the voltage?

Comment: @SirPattalot none at all.

Comment: I appreciate the help. I edited my question after you answered so swiftly, one final question: can i plug the d0 and d1 lines directly into the Arduino, or do i need to manage the voltage?

Comment: I think Wiegand is an open drain protocol. Turn on the internal pull-ups of your digital pins and the keypad pulls them down like buttons.

Comment: So in that case, direct into Arduino SHOULD be fine?

Comment: According to Wikipedia: `The Wiegand interface uses three wires, one of which is a common ground and two of which are data transmission wires usually called DATA0 and DATA1, alternately labeled "D0" and "D1" or "Data Low" and "Data High". When no data is being sent, both DATA0 and DATA1 are pulled up to the "high" voltage level — usually +5 VDC. When a 0 is sent the DATA0 wire is pulled to a low voltage while the DATA1 wire stays at a high voltage. When a 1 is sent the DATA1 wire is pulled to a low voltage while DATA0 stays at a high voltage.` -- so yes, it's fine.